# ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API with MySQL keep throwing DataReader Open exception

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a web service with ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API, using MySQL, with his .NET Connector (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net.html);

But on my tests when I make 3 simultaneous requests from my HTML5 client to my web service, it returns me the correct data sometimes of 2 or 1 requests only, the other requests throw me a 505 error, saying that already exists a DataReader object associated with the connection, more specifically:

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)   
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at App.Backservice.Models.Persistence.DataTable..ctor(MySqlDataAdapter adp)
```

Besides the error is on DataReader complaint, I'm currently using only DataTables, but I'm expecting that the driver use DataReader to load the DataTable...

I can't find why it keeps throwing me this error. My connection with the data base is not persistant, I hope so, I was expecting one connection per request.

Anyone ever had this happening before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if the underlying object is using a `DataReader`, as you mention. In this case, you must have synchronous access to the database connection. `DataReader`s open a connection, and maintain it *busy* until the `DataReader` is `Close`d.

The .NET Framework makes great use of [Connection Pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool), and therefore several connections to the same database will actually try to be one real established connection (if possible). Due to several web requests happening at the same time, this connection pooling is good, however, `DataReader`s are "breaking" that advantage.

In order to help with this, create a static `Object` (and instantiate) somewhere in your application. Proceed to encapsulate the code that accesses MySQL with the following:

```
lock (_StaticLockingObject)
{
    // Data access code here
}
```

Comment: It worked fine, I just created the static object and wrapped with the lock at the data base access code. Thank's a lot!